# How can I attach an existing EBS volume to an EC2 instance with Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I've looked through the Ansible documentation for [ec2_instance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_instance_module.html) and [ec2_vol](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_vol_module.html) but both seem to only support creating a new EBS volume (either blank or from an EBS snapshot). I would like to attach an existing EBS volume directly to an instance, not create a snapshot of it and then create a new volume from that snapshot. Is there an Ansible module that does this or should I just use `shell` and run [the right AWS CLI command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/attach-volume.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the union of the [`id:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_vol_module.html#parameter-id) and [`instance:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_vol_module.html#parameter-instance) properties, as indicated by the language next to the `id:` property:

> Volume id if you wish to attach an existing volume (requires instance) or remove an existing volume

```yaml
- amazon.aws.ec2_vol:
    id: '{{ my_volume_id }}'
    instance: '{{ my_inst_id }}'
    device_name: /dev/xvdf # or whatever
```

Be aware (as this bit me) when they say `instance: "None"` to detach it, they really mean `None`, and not `null` or whatever else